# Execute shell command without filtering from Vim

Tags: vim, shell

I want to select a block of text (for example, `V%`) and use the text as input to a shell command (for example, `wc` or `pbcopy`) - but I *don't* want to alter the current buffer - I just want to see the output of the command (if any) then continue editing without any changes.

Typing `V%!wc` translates to `:'<,'>!wc` and switches the block of text for the output of the `wc` command.

How do you pipe a chunk of text to an arbitrary shell command without affecting the current buffer?

Comment: If you want to pipe your text selection into the OS clipboard (pbcopy on OS X), you can just use the * yank buffer. In visual mode type: "*y

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Select your block of text, then type these keys :w !sh

The whole thing should look like:

```
:'<,'>w !sh
```

That's it. Only took me 8 years to learn that one : )

note: typing : after selecting text produces :'<,'> a range indicating selection start and end.

**Update 2016: This is really just one use of the generic:**

```
'<,'>w !cli_command
```

Which basically lets you "send" arbitrary parts of your file to external commands and see the results in a temporary vi window without altering your buffer. Other useful examples would be:

```
'<,'>w !wc
'<,'>w !to_file my_file
```

I honestly find it more useful to alter the current buffer. This variety is simply:

```
'<,'>!wc
'<,'>!to_file my_file
```

Comment: Awesome, neat and builtin --- all one could hope for.

Comment: Documented at `:help :write_c` for those curious.

Answer (score 4):

One possibility would be to use `system()` in a custom command, something like this:

```
command! -range -nargs=1 SendToCommand <line1>,<line2>call SendToCommand(<q-args>) 

function! SendToCommand(UserCommand) range
    " Get a list of lines containing the selected range
    let SelectedLines = getline(a:firstline,a:lastline)
    " Convert to a single string suitable for passing to the command
    let ScriptInput = join(SelectedLines, "\n") . "\n"
    " Run the command
    let result = system(a:UserCommand, ScriptInput)
    " Echo the result (could just do "echo system(....)")
    echo result
endfunction
```

Call this with (e.g.):

```
:'<,'>SendToCommand wc -w
```

Note that if you press `V%:`, the `:'<,'>` will be entered for you.

```
:help command
:help command-range
:help command-nargs
:help q-args
:help function
:help system()
:help function-range
```

Comment: My first thought was that it looked really chunky and verbose, but after adding chucking it in my .vimrc and adding a mapping, it's perfect:

vmap # :SendToCommand<Space>

Now I can just do V%# and bang out the command name.  Just what I wanted.

Comment: Glad you like it!  Your mapping looks like a good idea (I do tend to go for long and verbose command names and rely on tab-completion to save me the effort).  Consider putting it in `~/.vim/plugin/sendtocommand.vim` or `~/.vim/autoload/sendtocommand.vim` (the latter will require some changes) to help keep your vimrc manageable.

Answer (score 1):

**Update: my answer is nonsense.**

@pixelearth's answer is good, but I had a little trouble understanding what he did exactly, so I wrote the following. This sequence of commands let's you execute `wc -l` on your visual selection. `wc -l` simply counts the number of lines passed to it.

1. In Vim go into Visual Mode using `v`
2. Select a few lines by going down: `jjjj`
3. Type `:` which Vim will *translate* to `:'<,'>`
4. Type `w !wc -l`, your complete commandline should now be `:'<,'>w !wc -l`
5. Press Enter to get the result of your command (in this example it would be 4)
6. Press Enter to continue editing

I don't understand what exactly happens at step 3 and 4 but I do know that it works.

Comment: This isn't really the same thing at all. What you're doing is manually typing the command !wc -l, what is being done above is that the command you want to execute IS ALREADY IN THE VIM FILE. So if you had wc -l on a line by itself, you could use the method above to pipe THAT command to !sh (the shell).

Comment: @pixelearth You're right, I just did not understand the original question.

Comment: Revisiting this after several years, I can see that while what you're doing isn't exactly the same thing, it's still really cool. You're basically using the selected text as INPUT for following command. Equally useful.

Comment: For those confused about the `'<,'>` bit: check out `:help '<` and `:help mark-motions` inside Vim. Things that start with apostrophe (`'`) are "marks". Vim has these special marks for the beginning and end of the visual selection. A colon-command in Vim can be applied to a given region of the file by specifying that region (with marks, or other methods) just after the colon. So `:'<,'>...` reads as "From mark `<` to mark `>`, run command `...`"

Comment: If your answer is nonsense (as you state), why don't you delete it?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not the ideal solution, but if all else fails, you could always just press <kbd>u</kbd> after running the command to undo the buffer change.

Comment: Sure, that's what I do currently - I'm just hoping I'm missing something.  I guess if there isn't a built-in way of doing this, a small <code>cmap</code> could do the trick - anyone got a ready-made one?

Comment: After glancing around on meta-SO, using `backticks around text` apparently is supposed to allow code-formatting in comments.